# PowerPivot Drill Through Formatting

Tags: powerpivot

Does anyone know a way to carry formatting through in a PowerPivot drill through? Whenever I do Drill Throughs on a PowerPivot workbook the report generated does not have the formatting set in PowerPivot, it just has the raw formatting from the table.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the default table colors do this:

1. Double click to drill down and view the page.
2. Your tab now says Table Tools..
3. In Table Styles group click the lower right drop down button to view all styles
4. At the bottom see "New Table Style..."
5. Find the check box at the bottom of this dialog (New Table Quick Style) "Set as default table quick style for this document"

You'll have to use macros if you want to do anything else, this how I have accomplished column hiding in the past:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable 
Dim pf As PivotField 
Dim pi As PivotItem 

Set pt = Me.PivotTables("PivotTable1") ' replace with your PT name (see in pivot table options)

For Each pf In pt.PivotFields 
    If pf.Name = "Field1" Then ' change this to your field name
        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems 
            pi.ShowDetail = True ' True to show, False to Hide
    Next pi 
End If 
Next pf
```

Another way to accomplish this via macro is putting something like this in the workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
ans = MsgBox("Format this sheet?", vbYesNo)
If ans = vbYes Then blahh Sh
End Sub
```

Then put this in the tandard code module:

```
Sub blahh(sht As Worksheet)
MsgBox "formatting new sheet: " & sht.Name
End Sub
```

Tested and works with a pivot table, Excel 2007 already adds some styling to the drill down sheet.